# React native - react navigation routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Hi Guys I am creating a react  native app with react navigation for routing.
When I do click the route of the parent tab its showing an error same like in the screenshot below.
I have tried restart server also after I saw a solution here in stack-overflow still same error showing.

I am using mac and this error occurs in ios emulator ,

error screen shot in emulator
[image]

my component

```
class Maincomp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(
              StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [
                  NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Subcomp'}),
                ],
              }),
            );
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text>sub page Reset</Text>

            <Icon name="keyboard-arrow-right" size={25} color="#0E65B4" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

    const Maincomp = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Maincomp: {
          screen: Maincomp,
        },
        Subcomp: {
          screen: Subcomp,
        },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Maincomp',
      },
    );
    
    export default createAppContainer(Maincomp);
```

Comment: where is Subcomp written?

Comment: it is normal component outside this component and imported @GauravRoy.  actually  I am trying to make this nested navigation work so created a component outside and trying to route to that component when the link is clicked here